# expression to hide multiple tablix in ssrs 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have 4 tablix in my ssrs report (WTD/MTD/QTD/YTD), i have created a parameter to select between these 4 tablix, can any one please let me know expression for hiding the tablix based upon the selection from the parameter, WTD should be default and if i select mtd, qtd and ytd should be hidden.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you select the tablix properties --> Visibility --> show or hide based on an expression. If your parameter value is WTD, for the tablix the expression should be `=IIF(Parameters!Myparameter.Value = "WTD",TRUE,FALSE)' you have to do this for all the tablixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the Tablix, under Visibility you will 3 options "Show, Hide, Show or Hide based on an expression". Please ensure you select "Show or hide based on an expression".

For example in order to display WTD when WTD is selected it would be 
Your expression should be the following:

```
Parameters!ParameterName.Value <> 'WTD'
```

Then this table will be hidden when the value is not WTD.

Similarly in order to display MTD 
Your expression should be the following:

```
Parameters!ParameterName.Value <> 'MTD'
```

By default, within SSRS you only add Hidden expression.

Hope this helps.