# Use a multiselectbox to hide or show chosen tablix

Tags: reporting-services

i have 3 Tablix (Tablix1,Tablix2,Tablix3).
I got a Parameter (selectbox) where the User can select all Tablix he wants to see. The other Tablix should be hidden. 
I can so it with a dropdown Menu with one Option to choose, but not with multiple Choices.
I dont know how to do this, help please.
[Similar Topic with no answer that works for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41452207/expression-to-hide-multiple-tablix-in-ssrs-2008/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily.

Assuming your multi-value parameter is called `myParameter` and you parameter values are as follows

```
Label      Value
"Tablix 1"   1
"Tablix 2"   2
"Tablix 3"   3
```

Then you can set the `visibility` property of each Tablix as follows

```
=Join(Parameters!myParameter.Value,",").Contains(1)=False
```

Change the (1) to (2) or (3) for each tablix.

The expression basically joins the selected parameter values together into a single string then we do a "contains" to check if the value exists.

**Note:** This will only work for 0-9, if you had a value of '10' and we checked for '1' then this would incorrectly return true but as you only have 3 tablix then you'll be fine.

Comment: If you have values greater than 9 then have a tablix hidden based on checking for '1' if will not work as it will see the '1' in '10'. You can get round this by settings values to be 001, 002, 003 etc and then adjust the contains method to look for '001' etc.

Comment: You´re right, now i testet it with Tablix 1 & 11.
When i select 1 he shows Tablix 1, when i select 11 he shows 1 and 11.
Will try the solution with the leading zeros!

Answer (score 0):

Someone may be along with a more elegant solution shortly but an inelegant solution that will definitely work is to have 3 separate parameters, one for each table. Call them table 1 table 2 and table 3 and have the prompt be something like "Do you want to see table 1?" with a boolean data type.

Then you can set the visibility expression for each table individually with the "Hidden" expression being

```
= Parameters!table1.value = False
```

for table one and so on. Not as user friendly as a drop down box but it will work and probably isn't too onerous.